# HTML & JavasScript Navigation by only changing text

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, navigation, switch-statement

I'm trying to build a webpage where the navigation bar on the top simply changed the contents of main tag so if later on there are any changes to the look of the website, I don't need to modify every single html file to keep the same content.

```js
function selection(){
  var content = document.getElementById("content");
  var link = document.getElementsById("nav-bar");
  li = nav-bar.getElementById();
    
  switch(li){
    case "index":
      content.innerHTML = index();
      break;
    case "about":
      content.innerHTML = about();
      break;
    case "contact":
      content.innerHTML = contact();
       break;
    }
}
    
function index(){
  return "Index content";
}
    
function about() {
  return "About content";
}
    
function contact(){
  return "Contact content";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="nav.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
    
<body>
  <header></header>
  <nav id="nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a id="index">Index</a></li>
      <li><a id="about">About</a></li>
      <li><a id="contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main id="content"></main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the point of the functions in your switch case, if all they are doing is returning a predefined value?

Comment: Depending what the user pressed, the function changes what the content is. Those returned strings are just examples to what it might change to.